# PHP Reading Session in Form Submit File

Tags: php, session

for secure i want to read the Session in the Form Submit and dont want to give the userid in hidden input field.

The Problem is, i dont get anything in the action php file.

i tried `print_r($_SESSION);` but there is nothing.
If i add `print_r($_SESSION);` in the PHP file, where i will create a new mysql query with form, it gives userid = 1 back.

Also i can `print_r($_SESSION['userid']);` to get only userid. But not in the action file where i will save the new post...

In Short:
The Session is clear after submit in the php file

Comment: [Read How To Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i add short info :D Think thats enaugh... session is clear after submit

Comment: It isn't. Post your code.

Comment: Which Code? Thats all... print_r($_SESSION); there comes nothing after submit. But in the form php file it has set userid and i can read it with print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Put your submit. Put the code that brought you to having to ask this question. Otherwise no one will answer, because we cannot see anything you can see. If you have the words, print_r($_SESSION) on a PHP file with no other code, then of course it doesn't work the way you want it to. 
[Click Me and Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This kind of problem might be occurs for many reasons. You should submit your php code here for better understanding to others.